# problem with vulkan floating point behavior

Tags: floating-point, glsl, precision, vulkan

I try to implement the paper [Extended-Precision Floating-Point Numbers for
GPU Computation by Andrew Thall, Alma College](http://andrewthall.org/papers/df64_qf128.pdf) in a GLSL Vulkan compute shader.
I need this because some of my devices don't support double precision.

My problem is in the quickTwoSum function

```
vec2 quickTwoSum( float a , float b) {
    float s = a + b;
    float t = s - a;
    float e = b - t;
    return vec2(s, e);
}
```

for example

```
a = 114251.609
b = -0.00107500004
```

then this happens

```
s = 114251.609 // this is correct because b is to small
t = -0.00107500004 // <= why? (s - a) should be 0 
e = 0.0 // <= this is wrong because t is wrong
```

Why is **t** not correct? It seems the GPU stores more precise in the background than the 32bit float variable can actually hold.

Is it a GPU problem? I use an NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M.
On my CPU this works how it should.

And I have found someone who has implemented it for OpenGL https://www.thasler.com/blog/blog/glsl-part2-emu. So it should also work on GPU.

It would be nice if someone can help me.

***UPDATE***:

Here are my [programm files](https://donovan.ilr.ing.tu-bs.de/owncloud/index.php/s/6076VDmDztODM0b)

**cbc.com**: glsl shader

**glsl_compiler_output.txt**: the output of the glslangValidator

**cbc_comp.spv**: shader compiled to SPIR-V

**main.cpp**: was a mandelbrot vulkan compute example, which I changed to my needs

**vulkantest_output.txt**: output of my program

Comment: Can you check the instructions generated by the compiler? Maybe it is optimizing away the arithmetic it thinks is redundant.

Comment: Can you show us how you debugged this? Very good question btw.

Comment: Also to clarify on @EricPostpischil 's point, because t is the same as a + b -a, a fastmath optimizing compiler could theoretically compile such a statement to just b, but that would violate compiler guarantees for non-fastmath compilations. unless you are using the [spirv optimizer](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Tools), I would think this would be on the vendor side (ie it might not even show up in SPIR-V).

Comment: Maybe the compiler is optimizing it.

Comment: @whn I have added the files.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I have checked the glslangValidator output and it seems everything is how it should be

Comment: @JLo  Everything looks correct to me as well, I see and add and a sub, it looks like a case of the post SPIR-V process, I believe Nvidia compiles SPIR-V to LLVM then to PTX then to gpu assembly, so the could be optimizing at any point in that pipeline.  I vaguely remember seeing some arithmetic instructions that restricted optimization in SPIR-V but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @JLo it looks like if your SPIR-V had the SignedZeroInfNanPreserve  OpExecutionMode you might be able to stop optimizations http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Registry/blob/master/extensions/KHR/SPV_KHR_float_controls.html but this applies to the whole entrypoint.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but `0` result assumes specific rounding mode, otherwisely it could be _some_ negative value.

Comment: Could it need a `precise` qualifier for values? Not sure how it translates to SPIR-V, but glsl spec says `"The qualifier precise will ensure that operations contributing to a variable's value are done in their stated
order and are done with operator consistency"`

Comment: Are you using 1.3 or higher?  I noticed this ominous blurb @ https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)" "Warning: The specific sizes and formats for integers and floats in GLSL are only for GLSL 1.30 and above. Lower versions of GLSL may not use these exact specifications."